# Windows hangs during defragmentation

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, crash, file-recovery, file-corruption

So I was defragmenting my disk and let the computer sort it out. I was going to look for something when I noticed that windows didnt react. No matter the input from mouse or keyboard, my monitor light was blinking (indicates sleep mode). The disk was also not making any operations and since a BSOD didnt seem like something that would happen, I forcefully rebooted my PC. Event log logged only a critical power loss and nothing else meaningful to me. My question is whether I can trust that my data kept its integrity. I know NTFS uses journaling but am not exactly sure about the full capabilities of it. Does NTFS use some sort of data verification or something similar or is a reinstall in order (I am quite paranoid about my data)? I also have a recent pre-crash restore point. Does that help in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Restore points are stored in the filesystem, so if filesystem is corrupted, so can be restore points.

Run a filesystem check: right-click the system disk, choose *Properties → Tools* tab and choose to check the filesystem. Windows will tell you that it can't check a disk while it's running off of it, so you have to reboot. Agree. The check can take some time, even up to a few hours on large and slow drives.

If any corruption is found, this tool will try to sort it out. It sometimes involves deleting files that cannot be salvaged. If you don't have backups, let this be a lesson. If you do, that's great! You may need them.

You can run a system integrity check afterwards: run *Command line* as administrator (search for it in the Start menu, right click &rarr _Run as administrator) and type `sfc /scannow` <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will also take some time and internet connection will be required to repair detected issues.